# Decode function not working in SQL*Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am using SQL*Loader to import data from CSV to an Oracle table. My data has multiple date fields and i need to replace null values with '0001-01-01-00-00-00' and other values need to follow date format.

I used decode option like

```
decode(:QUOTE_CREATE_DT,NULL,'0001-01-01-00.00.00',
  TO_DATE(:QUOTE_CREATE_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

which is not working when null values occur.

SQL*Loader error:

```
Record 2: Rejected - Error on table EX_QUOTE_MO_SAMPLE, column QUOTE_CREATE_DT.
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version is relying on implicit conversion using the SQL*Loader session's NLS settings.

You could use `decode` or `coalesce` or `nvl` to provide a date *string* in the format you're converting, but inside the `to_date()` call:

```
QUOTE_CREATE_DT "TO_DATE(NVL(:QUOTE_CREATE_DT, '01/01/0001'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')"
```